# Retaining font size in PowerPoint even in Master Slide?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

Is there any way to force a font style/size, even in a Master Slide, not to change and Autofit in a slide.

I have as a fifth level bullet setting a 14pt font. It's getting changed to a 13pt font based on Autofit. I reset the slide to no avail. I do not want to fix manually as I want the change to stay put. I have tried the various Autofit options, but none preserve the original intent.

All options seem to lead to sort sort of change.

Thanks in advance for your help. I am working in PowerPoint 2013.

Best,

Justin